# Directory not empty error while renaming folders

Tags: python

Im trying to rename folders,

This is what i have,

```
for item in all_folders:
    root_path = '/media/username/da5df9e4-cdc6-4d55-91e8-b2383e89165f/lion/'
        new_root_path = root_path+item
        for folders in os.listdir(root_path+item):
            for index,value in enumerate(all_combined):
                if folders.startswith(all_combined[index]):
                       os.rename(os.path.join(new_root_path,folders),os.path.join(new_root_path,'New'))
```

When i run this i get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last) 
<ipython-input-320-a1b27e11ba34> in <module>()
      4     for index,value in enumerate(all_combined):
      5         if folders.startswith(all_combined[index]):
----> 6                     os.rename(os.path.join(new_root_path,folders),os.path.join(new_root_path,'New'))

OSError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/media/username/da5df9e4-cdc6-4d55-91e8-b2383e89165f/lion/Tpct046/5mm portal' -> '/media/username/da5df9e4-cdc6-4d55-91e8-b2383e89165f/lion/Tpct046/New'
```

all_folders list looks like this:

```
['t0118',
 't046',
 't042',
 't003',
 't024',
 't016',
 't011',
 't065',]
```

The all_combined list looks like this:

```
 all_combined = ['Thin Venous Phase',
 'VENOUS THIN',
 'Tripple Phase',
 'Thin Venous Phase',
 'Thin Venous Phase',
 'Thin Venous Phase',
 '5MM VEN0US',
 'ARTERIAL THIN_0081',
 'ARTERIAL THIN_0100',.........]
```

Any suggestions what may help would be useful,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this directory exist ?

 '/media/username/da5df9e4-cdc6-4d55-91e8-b2383e89165f/lion/Tpct046/New'

Comment: yes it does exist

Comment: Try mv  '/media/username/da5df9e4-cdc6-4d55-91e8-b2383e89165f/lion/Tpct046/5mm portal'   '/media/username/da5df9e4-cdc6-4d55-91e8-b2383e89165f/lion/Tpct046/New'

and check if you are getting same error or not

Comment: you mean in the command line?

Comment: Yes , in the command line

Comment: alright one sec

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162946/discussion-between-akhil-thayyil-and-ryan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
for item in all_folders:
    root_path = '/media/username/da5df9e4-cdc6-4d55-91e8-b2383e89165f/lion/'
        new_root_path = os.path.join(root_path,item)
        for folders in os.listdir(os.path.join(root_path,item)):
            for index,value in enumerate(all_combined):
                if folders.startswith(all_combined[index]):
                       os.rename(os.path.join(new_root_path,folders),os.path.join(new_root_path,folders+'New'))
```